# Read value of environment variable in Java

Tags: java, environment-variables

I am setting the value an env. variable (say runOnEnv) in my terminal as:

```
export runOnEnv=dev
```

But when I am trying t access it in my java code like:

```
String envVarValue = System.getenv("runOnEnv");
```

The value of this comes out to be null.

Am I missing something? If not how can this be done ?

Comment: Surely `System.getenv( "runOnEnv" )`?

Comment: @SurajMenon - Would you care to share what was wrong? I am in similar situation

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you mean `System.getenv( "runOnEnv" )` -- including hyphens.

Are you running your Java program in the same shell as the `export ...`? You should be aware that `export` makes the variable available to the process and subprocesses, not parent processes - thus it won't be available in another shell.

Hope that helps.

Cheers,